# Constructing bounded funcions that converge uniformly on compact sets.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Assume you have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
>   that is $C^2$. That is: $f,\frac{\delta f}{\delta x},\frac{\delta
> f}{\delta y},\frac{\delta^2 f}{\delta x\delta y},\frac{\delta^2
> f}{\delta x^2},\frac{\delta^2 f}{\delta y^2}$ exist and are
>   continuous.
>
> I need to create a sequence of functions $f_n$, which are $C^2$ and
>   bounded and the corresponding derivatives exist, and are bounded, and
>   converge uniformly on compact sets to $f$.

How do I create this sequence?

My first Idea is to define using polar coordinates: $f_n(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=f(r\wedge n\cos\theta,r\wedge n \sin \theta).$ Then I have that the function is bounded etc., but I have no control over the derivatives in the at the edge of the circle $\bar{B}(n)$.

Is there an easy way to choose this sequence?

Since the function and all the derivatives are continuous, it seems like I need to just define it on bigger and bigger compact sets. Since on each compact set a continuous function is bounded. But the problem comes at the edges of those compact sets, I need to do something in order to have differentiability and continuity here as well.

If I was in one variable the problem would be easier because then I could choose:

$f_n(x)=f(x)\mathcal{X}_{[-n,n]}(x)+$

$\mathcal{X}_{(n,\infty)}(x)(f(n)+f''(n)+f'(n)\sin(x-n)-f''(n)\cos(x-n))+$

$\mathcal{X}_{(-\infty,-n)}(x)(f(-n)+f''(-n)+f'(-n)\sin(x+n)-f''(-n)\cos(x+n))$

But I am not quite sure how to transfer this to the multidimensional case.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't hard to construct a $C^\infty$ function $\phi$ with the property that $0 \le \phi \le 1$, $\phi(x) = 1$ if $|x| \le 1$, and $\phi(x) = 0$ if $|x| \ge 2$. You can use $$f_n(x) = f(x) \phi(x/n).$$ Just observe that $f_n(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ with $|x| \le n$.

Comment: But this is in one dimension?

Comment: @user119615 Once you have a $\phi$ in one dimension, the function $\phi(|x|^2)$ handles all dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, may I ask how you construct this function?